# Emacs gone from Mac OS Terminal - Only GUI version left

Tags: bash, emacs

I have recently removed Emacs from my Mac OSX Yosemite, and have a beginner's beginner's problem in re-installing it and running it from the terminal. I can open the Emacs app GUI from the Applications folder, but cannot use Emacs from within the Terminal whatsoever.

I removed the old version of Emacs by using the command:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/emacs
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/share/emacs
```

Then I installed the newest version of Emacs through Homebrew, using the code

```
$ brew install emacs --with-cocoa.
```

Now, when I type the command emacs in the terminal, I get  "/usr/local/bin/emacs: No such file or directory."

I tried to add the following lines in a file named "emacs" in /usr/local/bin:

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```

But now, when I type the command emacs in the terminal I get: "-bash: /usr/local/bin/emacs: Permission denied"

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me that you forgot to `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/emacs`.

Comment: Thanks, as a total beginner however, I am not sure what this means. I just type this command once in the command line? What does it do?

Comment: @PeterNilsson It adds the **executable** permission to the script, which indicates that you're allowed to run the file as a program.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script, use a symbolic link.

```
$ ln -s /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs /usr/bin/emacs
```

Comment: Thanks, do I just create this link once in the command line or do I have to put it in a file? For learning purpose, I would also be very thankful if someone could explain my problem and how it would be solved by a symbolic link.

Comment: You do it once. A symbolic link is like an alias.